# Implementing Dask scheduler and workers on Docker containers

Tags: python, docker, dask, parquet, dask-distributed

I need to run a scikit-learn RandomForestClassifier with multiple processes in parallel. For that, I'm looking into implementing a Dask scheduler with N workers, where the scheduler and each worker run in a separate Docker container.

The client application, that also runs in a separate Docker container, will first connect to the scheduler and initiate the scikit-learn process with `with joblib.parallel_backend('dask'):`.

The data to train the machine learning model is stored in parquet in the client application Docker container. What is the best practice to have the workers access the data?  Should the data be located somewhere else, in a shared directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Apach Parquet is a files-system based, it all depends on the architecture that you are building, meaning will your project run on a single server or it will be distributed across multiple servers.

If you are running on a single server, then simple share of the `docker volume` between the containers, or even a common mount over the local file storage will do the job.

If, on the other hand, you are trying to set up a distributed training over multiple servers, then you will need some type of file server to handle the files.

One of the simple ways to share files is trough an `NFS` server and one of the commonly used images for this is [erichough/nfs-server](https://hub.docker.com/r/erichough/nfs-server/). You will need to use this container to `export` the local folder(s) where the files are stored and you will need to `mount` the `fs` on the remaining servers.

Comment: Assuming that there's a single server with all these containers, each worker will load the data from the file system? How does each worker know what portion of the data to load/process?

Comment: You can partition them with Apache Parquet as in [this example](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html) and load each partition to a dataframe in the container as in [this example](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html#reading-from-partitioned-datasets)

Comment: How do I tell the worker what they need to do? My code is in the client application, how to tell the worker which code to execute?

Comment: This also depends, if you have static model, the model will be in the worker containers, if you have dynamic model (changing for each training), you will share your code together with the files and run it from the containers. Also there are tools like `Dataiku` or `Kubeflow` which are automating all of this "infrastructure" work

Comment: I have a static model, the only thing that changes is the data, so I need to understand how to set the code in the worker containers, any links that point to that? I cannot find any. thanks.

Comment: If you have static model, you will package the model in the container. The simples way to tell to the container which partition to work on is by creating environment variable (when you start the container from docker) in which you place the partition tag (name or number). Inside you python script you can use `os.environ.get('PARTITION')` where the `PARTITION` is the name of the environment variable. Check this [post](https://blog.cloudera.com/distributed-model-training-using-dask-and-scikit-learn/) to give you idea how a distributed learning is set-up with dusk and sklearn